# Xaml error when referencing internal classes in strongly-named assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, strongname

I have a peculiar problem regarding internal classes used from xaml.

The problem is as follows:

We decided to strong-name all our assemblies. After the strong-naming, all but one project compiles without a hitch under VS 2017. The situation is as follows:

- Assembly Company.Component - Compiles without problems, and exposes its internals as follows:

  ```
  [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Company.Component.Test, PublicKey={omitted}")]
  [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Company.OtherLibrary, PublicKey={omitted}")]
  ```
- Assembly Company.Component.Test - Compiles without problems, and can access internals in Company.Component just fine. All tests pass.
- Company.OtherLibrary - Does not compile at all, due to the following error in one of its xaml files:

  ```
  Only public or internal classes can be used within markup. 'Converter1' is not public or internal.
  ```

The xaml file in question can be seen below (with names changed):

```
<ns:class x:Class="Company.OtherLibrary.Class"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                   xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Company.Component.Converters;assembly=Company.Component"
                   xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Company.OtherLibrary.ViewModels"

                   xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:Company.Component;assembly=Company.Component"
                   mc:Ignorable="d"
                   d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
                   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=viewModels:ViewModelClass}"
                   Style="{StaticResource  {x:Type ns:Style}}">
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <DockPanel>
            <DockPanel.Resources>
                <converters:Converter1 x:Key="Converter1" />
                <converters:Converter2 x:Key="Converter2" />
                <converters:Converter3 x:Key="Converter3" />
                <converters:Converter4 x:Key="Converter4" />
            </DockPanel.Resources>
...
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

**Now to answer some questions:**

1. The public key is the correct public key (not only the token) of the OtherLibrary assembly. It is in fact the same one used for the test assembly.
2. The assembly name for OtherLibrary is the same as the one in its properties.
3. The code worked before the strong naming. No changes have been made to any code file in the projects (bar AssemblyInfo.cs). I have checked with VS 2017 git compare. The edited lines are the ones shown, and the edit is to insert public keys.
4. The xaml-namespaces can sometimes be found, and sometimes not. This only goes for the namespaces that have no public classes.
5. All converters seen in the dock panel resources are internals in the Company.Component assembly. They all give the following error:

   ```
   The type '{type}' is not accessible.
   ```
6. All libraries are built against the same version of the framework/dlls.
7. The assembly reference to Company.Component have 'copy local' set to true.

**What I've tried**

1. Clearing xaml shadow-cache
2. Cleaning and rebuilding.
3. Changing active build-configuration (both platform and Debug/Release).
4. Manually cleaning all bin and obj directories for all projects.
5. Restarted both computer and VS 2017.
6. All of the above at once.

There is something very simple that I've obviously overlooked. Can someone please help me figure out what is going on here? I am not allowed (for reasons left out) to change the component library other than strongly naming it.

Comment: If the converters are `internal` can you change them to `public`?

Comment: @XAMlMAX - That is indeed a possibility, but I would like to refrain from doing so. There are quite a few internals that will become public if I go down that route, and it is not desired.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior with 2 other dlls. One with `internal` converter and other exactly the same but using `public` converter?

Comment: _"Compiles without problems, and can access internals in Company.Component just fine"_ -- is there any XAML in that project? Conversely, can you in `Company.OtherLibrary` access internals from `Company.Component` from C#? I.e. is it just XAML that's not working, or do you have the problem in both XAML and C#?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Public converters works fine. There are reasons not to want this, however, as that will expose much of the underlying structure as public.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Internals can be accessed from C# just fine. The test project does not contain any XAML. The one thing that boggles my mind is that this worked before strongly naming the assemblies.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and) it describes another way of including your assemblies in the xaml. Maybe it will help.